# How to increase temp space in fedora 20

Tags: fedora, oracle-database

I need to install oracle 11g in my PC. So I have installed fedora 20 in VMware virtual machine and now I need to install oracle. I tried it several times, and every time I'm getting the same error.

It looks like there is not enough space in `/temp` When I installed fedora 20 I added 60Gb space as I recall. If I reinstall fedora 20 and add more space then will I be able to get through this problem?

[image: Snap shot of error]

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Fedora 20 is [EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life). You should update to the current release to get some support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your /tmp partition has 490MB, while the Oracle Universe Installer expects at least 500MB. Depends on the parition type, you may consider:

- if you are using a setup based on logical volumes, you can extend the size of the /tmp partition
- mount another partition for /tmp (either the primary partition or any other partition, that will ensure at least 500MB of free space)
- add a 2nd disk in VMware and use it for the /tmp partition (a disk with a size of 1GB should be enough)
- create a file (using the dd command) of the desired size, add a file system on it and mount it as /tmp